# MySql get sum of subselect as column of parent select

Tags: mysql, subquery

Here is what I'm trying to do.   get a sum of the count of values from a table based on specific criteria and have this return as a column of the parent select, but I'm having trouble getting my head around the best (i.e. a workable) method for doing this.   I've tried

```
SELECT
sum(count(distinct(frsrvdate)))
FROM webusers.tblQAuditClaims qac inner join webusers.tblQAuditDetails qad using (claimId)
where qac.auditdate between '2012-01-01' and '2012-03-31'
and IsResubmitted = 0
and qad.errorflag = 0
and qac.errorflag = 0
which throws an invalid group function.
```

Starting to think I'm going down the wrong rabbit hole with my approach to this.  Any suggestions on what I'm missing?

I've pared it down to the subselect piece but still running in to problems on how to get a sum of the count.

Comment: Can you put your schema and some sample data up at http://sqlfiddle.com, then edit your question to show what your desired output will look like?

Comment: Is this honestly the smallest amount of SQL that demonstrates the problem? Rhetorical question there... it is **not**. Please see [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) then prune down your code to the bare minimum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first query you have an extra ).

Corrected one -

```
sum(SELECT count(distinct(FrSrvDate))
     FROM webusers.tblQAuditClaims qac Left Join webusers.tblQAuditDetails qad using     (claimId)
     where qac.auditdate between '2012-01-01' and '2012-03-31'
     and IsResubmitted = 0
     and qad.errorflag = 0
     group by tracenumber)
```